# Вывести в wp_list_pages дополнительную подпись к элементам

Tags: php, html, wordpress, веб-программирование

Мне нужно вывести такое описание дочерних страниц,
[image: 3 заголовка и снизу подписи, меню навигации]

но чтобы все было динамическое. Названия у меня получилось вывести, но через описание с помощью php переменных или что-то вроде описания страницы не получается. `the_field('')` не подходит, хочется более гибко сделать. 
Код с моими попытками:

```
<ul class="offer__tabs flex-column text-center text-md-left flex-md-row ml-lg-auto d-inline-flex justify-content-between">
    <?php
    if ((is_page('10'))) {
        $code = '<p class="offer__tab-text">' . the_content() . '</p>';
    } else {
        $code = '';
    }
    wp_list_pages(array(
        'child_of' => get_the_ID(),
        'title_li' => 0,
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'link_after' => $code
    )) ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте WP_Query и делайте любую разметку, которая вам нравится:

```
$query = new WP_Query( [
   'child_of' => get_the_ID(),
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
] );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```